# List of Kohana controllers

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I'm looking for a way to programatically get a list of controllers in a Kohana application.

Something like:

```
public function build_site_map(){
     $controllers = Kohana::get_controllers();

     echo '<ul>';
     foreach($controllers as $controller){
         echo '<li><a href="'.URL::base().$controller.'">'.$controller.'</a></li>';
     }
     echo '</ul>';
}
```

I realize I could read the /application/classes/controllers/ directory, but I'm hoping there's an easier way.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a list of your controller files could be done with `Kohana::list_files('classes/controller')`. But as Michal already said, there isn't a 1:1 realtionships between controllers/actions and routes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no `Kohana::get_controllers()` method that you can easily call to get a a sitemap of sorts. This is because controllers are called dynamically, i.e. based on the request's URL and Routes configuration Kohana's checking whether a controller (and action) exist and then call them. Kohana does not keep record of all available controllers and actions that can be accessible.

Neither traversing the `/application/classes/controllers` directory and getting the list of all files would give you the desired result, because there are not only actions to be read (which can be fairly easily done with [Reflection class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php)), but there are also [Routes](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing) which you have to take into account.

As you can see this is potentially very complex issue and one that cannot be simply answered with a snippet of code that can be pasted here.

If you decide to write a script that would actually create such a map, but you stumble into a problem on the way, we would be able to more helpful then otherwise this question is too open. Also, if you were to write it, I suggest you create it as a module that you would be able to include in any other projects and share it.

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution to get all the controllers and their actions. I use it to add permissions into our system https://github.com/open-classifieds/openclassifieds2/

```
/**
 * get all the controllers and the actions that can be used
 * @return array 
 */
public static function list_controllers()
{
    $list_controllers = array();

    $controllers = Kohana::list_files('classes/controller');

    foreach ($controllers as $controller) 
    {
        $controller = basename($controller,'.php');
        $list_controllers[] = $controller;

        $class      = new ReflectionClass('Controller_Panel_'.$controller);
        $methods    = $class->getMethods();
        foreach ($methods as $obj => $val) 
        {
            if (strpos( $val->name , 'action_') !== FALSE )
            {
                $list_controllers[$controller][] = str_replace('action_', '', $val->name);
            }
        }
    }

    return $list_controllers;
}
```